# How do I add a partial view with its own controller to another view in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view with just a single line called `Messages.ascx` which is in the location `~/Views/Shared/Messages.ascx`

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<h2><%:ViewBag.MyMessage.ToString() %></h2>
```

The controller of the partial view is as follows

```
public ActionResult Messages()
{
    ViewBag.MyMessage = "This is my Partial Message";
    return PartialView();
}
```

I just need the to add this partial view in my index.asp page which is located in `~/Views/Home/Index.aspx`. I added the partial view as follows

```
<%: Html.Partial("Messages") %>
```

However when I compile and run I get the following message on my browser

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
>
> ```
> Line 1:  <%@ Control Language="C#"> Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %> 
> Line 2:
> Line 3:  <h2><%:ViewBag.MyMessage.ToString() %></h2>
> ```

Kindly help me as to how do I add the partial view to my main view.

Comment: Where is `Messages` controller action method located?

Comment: The action method in located in Views/Shared/ folder

Comment: No, I mean `public ActionResult Messages()`, in which controller class is it located?

Comment: its located in public class MessagesController

Comment: try `@Html.Action(controllerName,actionName)` which does work . cheers

Comment: Fantastic.. Thanks a lot...super cool. it worked. though coz i am using aspx engine and not razor it worked with <%: Html.Action("Messages","Messages") %>. Thanks a lot man. But can you please explain why doesn't the above method work as it is most commonly documented. also which is a better engine to use aspx or razor. I am a very experienced programmer in web forms and wanna try out mvc. MVC doesn't seem too great so far, as there is nothing in MVC that i can't do with equal efficiency, speed and grace in webforms. but never the less i wanna give it a shot. Thanks once again.

Comment: the above method doesn't work beocz as per `html.partial` functionality it will not hit controller where your `ViewBag.MyMessage` declared/assigned . so you get null exception . razor is advanced to aspx engine for differences you can always refer google `engine` . hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this

```
<%: Html.Partial("Messages") %>
```

the content of `~/Views/Shared/Messages.ascx` will be rendered, but the controller action method below won't be executed

```
public ActionResult Messages()
{
    ViewBag.MyMessage = "This is my Partial Message";
    return PartialView();
}
```

so `ViewBag.MyMessage` is null and you got the error because of this syntax

```
<h2><%:ViewBag.MyMessage.ToString() %></h2>
```

You need to execute the controller action method using `Html.Action` method in your view. Since the controller class is `MessagesController`, change this syntax

```
<%: Html.Partial("Messages") %>
```

to this

```
<%: Html.Action("Messages", "Messages") %>
```